# Filtering entities with EF behind two joins without bringing the whole tables into datamodel

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Consider the following case, I have three tables

```
LampPost, columns: Id (PK, int), StreetId (FK, int)
Street,   columns: Id (PK, int), CityId (FK, int)
City,     columns: Id (PK, int), Name (varchar)
```

The usual case is that there are a lot (tens of thousands) of LampPosts per City. Let's say I'm creating a LampPost managing system, and I want to be able to filter LampPosts by city. But all I know about the table City is that it contains the two columns listed above. On one server, it might have additional columns, which I do not care about. And the same goes for the table Street.

Currently I have all the tables in my datamodel, which allows queries such as `context.LampPosts.Where(lp => lp.Street.City.Name == "Paris")`, but I'd really want to have another way of accomplishing this, without brining in the whole tables.

I also tried adding the tables to my data model (I'm using database first, EF 5 on .NET 4.0) and just removing the unneccessary columns, but EF complained about unmapped columns.

I'm pretty sure this can be done by either stored procs or some sort of executequery -calls, but I am very unfamiliar with both so I'm asking you guys, what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Is this about optimization or abstraction?

Comment: Abstraction (be able to filter by city name no matter how the city or street -table looks like, as long as they have the FKs and city has name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be creating a view for the table and select only required columns. Then you can bring the view into the data model.

For example if your `City` talbe looks like:

```
City (Id, Name, State, Population, Area)
```

you create a view for it like this:

```
CREATE VIEW CityView AS
SELECT Id, Name FROM City
```

and if `Street` looks like this:

```
Street (Id, Name, CityId, Length, Width)
```

(the columns are just for demonestration)

you can create it's view like:

```
CREATE VIEW StreetView AS
SELECT Id, Name, CityId FROM Street
```

All the required columns to navigate between entities are available.

Comment: If I create a view, I'm not able to edit the LampPosts right?

Comment: Create the view for `Street` and `City`. BTW, you can also edit views (it has some restrictions, but no problem here).

Comment: So lets say I created a view CityStreet, which contains StreetId, CityId, CityName. How would I then map this to the LampPosts to get the queries I want? And about editing views, would I have to create stored procs for insert, edit and delete myself for that to work or?

Comment: @bobblez You should create separate views for `Street` table and `City` table (those are separate tables, right?). Lets call them `CityView` and `StreetView`. Instead of `City` and `Street`, drop `CityView` and `Street` view onto model designer. Nothing else needs to be changed. `LampPosts` is the same as before. Also you can update the fileds of `CityView` and `StreetView` if required.

Comment: Yes, they are separate tables. But is it possible to then use the navigation properties of `LampPost` to drill into the Street and City? Basically, what would this line look like after changing the tables to views `context.LampPosts.Where(lp => lp.Street.City.Name == "Paris")`?

Comment: @bobblez Exactly the same. No change. Did you see my edited answer? Let's make it clearer.